# Chrome: jQuery element width at zoom levels other than 100%

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, zooming

Originally I set up a small test to find out how jQuery's `.width()` treats the different box models. Interestingly it shows the `width` defined in CSS minus the `padding-left` and `padding-right` for `border-box`. Now when I wrote this small test I **zoomed** the page so my colleague who was standing behind my desk could read the code from afar.

To see what I'm asking please proceed as follows:

1. Open the codepen example in Chrome: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoYeVg (it has to be on codepen since I cannot reproduce the same problem here in the snippet)
2. Click the first container. => **160**
3. Now wait 5 seconds until the text reverts to "click me"
4. Set page zoom to 175% by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>cmd</kbd> (Mac) and pressing <kbd>+</kbd> 4 times.
5. Now click the first container again. => **160.00001525878906**

Main Question: Why is it not exactly 160 any more at 175%?

Side Question: Why does jQuery treat both box models different in the way it does?

In Firefox I was unable to reproduce what seems to me like a decimal rounding problem/error. Anyone who knows exactly what is going on here?

Please check the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elem;
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    elem = $(this);
    elem.text(elem.width());
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.text("click me");
    }, 5000);
  });
})
```

```css
.a, 
.b {
  background-color: #a00;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 160px;
}

.a {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoYeVg -->
<div class="a">click me</div>
<div class="b">click me</div>
```

Comment: looks like the famed `subpixel issues`...

Comment: I cannot see the difference in 175%

Comment: @vel I can reproduce the issue on Mac OS X Sierra as well as on Windows 8.1.

Comment: On the side question: it's because the developers decided to get the content box size when using (width). Here's the post about it: https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/

Comment: Good find! Thanks for that @Iulian Anghel.